# create columns in csv based on existing column without pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the following structure in CSV
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5eBb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5eBb.png)

**Values to be stored in CSV :**

```
hashes = [('layer_1', 'start_1','40' ,'34'), ('layer_2', 'start_2','12','45')]
```

**What i want**

i need to write hashes values into csv based on id column

```
**id**
Street_1
S1L4
S1L3
S1L2
S1L1
Street_2
S2L3
S2L2
Street_3
S3L3
S3L2
Street_4
S4L3
S4L2
Street_5
S5L3
S5L4
S5L2
```

**conditions:**

- If id column contains Street_1,Street_2 and so on ...i need to leave it as blank
- In id S1L1 represents the Start_1 and Layer_1. If these values found in the list like below

  ('layer_1', 'start_1','40' ,'34')
  then i need to write the values 40 and 34 corresponding S1L1 row.

**What i have tried**

```
import csv
hashes = [('layer_1', 'start_1','40' ,'34'), ('layer_2', 'start_2','12','45')]
in_file = open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\input.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
out_file = open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(out_file)
for row in reader:
    
    temp = p[0]
    temp2 = p[1]
    temp3 = p[2]
    temp4= row[14]
    print(temp4)
    if temp4[-1] == int(temp[-1]) and temp4[-3] == int(temp2[-1]):
        writer.writerow(temp3)
   
    
in_file.close()    
out_file.close()
```

**i am expecting following output**

```
id           percentage     volume
Street_1        
S1L4        
S1L3        
S1L2        
S1L1              40         34
Street_2        
S2L3        
S2L2              12         45
Street_3        
S3L3        
S3L2        
Street_4        
S4L3        
S4L2        
Street_5        
S5L3        
S5L4        
S5L2
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this I wrote a little function that extracts the id from the hashes to create a dictionary for look ups to match against the input file. If an id in the input file is matched, it adds the data from that hash to the row, and writes it out.

**Update**
To conform with the OP's updated questions regarding rows before the `id` field two changes have been made:

1. `in_id = row[ 0 ]` -->  `in_id = row[ -1 ]` to use the last column as the `id`.
2. `out_row = [ in_id ]` --> `out_row = row` to preserve the row data, and append the hash data to it. With this update the `out_row` variable could be removed and operations could be made directly on `row`, however I have kept it in this example for consistency with the previous version.

```py
import re
import csv

def hash_id( h ):
    """
    :params h: Hash to parse.
    :returns: Id of the hash. 
    """
    layer_pattern = 'layer_(\d+)'
    start_pattern = 'start_(\d+)'
    
    layer_match = re.match( layer_pattern, h[ 0 ] )
    start_match = re.match( start_pattern, h[ 1 ] )
    
    layer = layer_match.group( 1 )
    start = start_match.group( 1 )
    
    idh = f'S{ start }L{ layer }'
    return idh

#--- main script ---

# create id-hash dictionary for look ups
id_hashes = { hash_id( h ): h for h in hashes }

with open( 'input.csv', newline = '' ) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader( infile )
    
    with open( 'output.csv', 'w', newline = '' ) as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer( outfile )
        
        for row in reader:
            in_id = row[ -1 ] # look up id from last column of the input file
            
            out_row = row
            if in_id in id_hashes:
                # input id found in hashes, add data
                matched_hash = id_hashes[ in_id ]
                out_row += matched_hash[ 2: ]
            
            # write output row
            writer.writerow( out_row )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code..its working absolutely fine...I have two additional columns also present before ID..i am getting weired output when i tried to add ..`writer.writerow( row[0] )writer.writerow( row[1] )` before `writer.writerow( out_row )`any help?

Comment: Because `writer.writerow()` will append the data as new rows instead of columns. Instead you should add the data in the `out_row` list. You can do this with something like `out_row = row[ :3 ] ` instead of `out_row = [ in_id ]`.

Comment: When i try to add ..now it's not writing the values which we have calculated

Comment: other values are adding.. i am addinf some thing like this `out_row = row[ :15 ]
            if in_id in id_hashes:
                # input id found in hashes, add data
                matched_hash = id_hashes[ :15 ]
                out_row += matched_hash[ :17 ]
            
            # write output row
           
            writer.writerow( out_row )`

Comment: It's quite difficult to debug the issue in the comments. You can add an update to your question with more details and I will see if I can resolve it.

Comment: i have added new image in the question can u check it..Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer and code to match the updated question.